# Browser: Different settings per NIC

Tags: proxy, internet, network-adapter, intranet, browser

The machine has two NIC's, each connecting to a separate network.

- Network A is Internet facing and requires a proxy to do so
- Network B is an Intranet

The problem is, if I set the proxy settings, I cannot access sites on Network B.  If I don't set them, I cannot access the Internet (on Network A).  Is there a way to set this up so I don't have to keep flipping this setting on and off?

The specific browser I'm using is Firefox, but I'm asking in more of a general sense.  Is this something I could configure on the NIC itself?

Comment: Please read our FAQ next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it per NIC, but you should be able to do it per address range. Look under Options, Advanced, Network, Connection, Settings, No proxy for.

Comment: I don't know how I've never seen that before, it was right in front of me!  I guess I just wasn't entirely sure what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: I do have one follow up question.  This option allows me to enter a domain name or IP range.  I don't suppose there's a way to do so for NetBIOS names (within that IP range) other than manually putting in each server, is there?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a proxy exclude list.

Add your intranet to the exclude list and use the proxy for everything else.